# Splash screen appears twice

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, splash-screen

I am new to Android programming. I am trying to make a splash screen that loads a profile page if the app is run for the first time using Shared Preferences. If the app is run for the second time, I wish to load a menu page. The problem is that the profile page opens but goes directly to the main menu. Also, the splash screen appears twice. Can someone please help?
My code:

```
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Handler;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;



  public class SplashActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);


            if (isFirstRun) {
                //show start activity

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,ProfilePage.class));
                getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();

            } else {

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainMenu.class));

            }


            // close this activity
            finish();

        }

    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}

  }
```

Comment: Show code of your ProfilePage.class. This code seems fine. I think you have a problem in ProfilePage activity

Answer (score 0):

i was using same way for splash as an activity but we should not load separate activity for splash.. we can set **Windowbackground** for our launcher screen.

so it will display that background till our main view loads completely.

here is nice tutorial regarding this https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: What is the best option to use Splash Screen through Windowsbackground, apply the theme in the same MainActivity or generate an activity launcher to manage the application launch? I am adding it to the MainActivity and after checking the authentication the Login screen appears and the Splash Screen is executed again without the first one, the original one, having disappeared, displaying a strange double effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code snippet in your splash screen activity:

```
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // finish the splash activity so it can't be returned to
                    SplashScreen.this.finish();
                }
            }, 3000); // 3000 milliseconds
        }
```

Comment: The splash screen issue is solved but the profile page immediately jumps to the next screen. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

change this code `

```
Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);`
```

to

```
    your_shared_pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SplashActivity.this);

Boolean isFirstRun = your_shared_pref.getBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
```

and the next line to edit shared_pref to

```
your_shared_pref.edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun",false).commit();
```

Comment: I am getting error for Boolean isFirstRun = your_shared_pref.getBoolean("isFirstRun", MODE_PRIVATE); String boolean cannot be applied to String int.

Comment: yeah, put a  null check there, it will be null for the first time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @inkedTechie .

Comment: if(isFirstRun!=null && isFirstRun)

Comment: getBoolean (String, boolean) in SharedPreferences cannot be applied to (String, int) @inkedTechie

Comment: i am so sorry, please change that to false.