# Splash screen load twice when the app is opened for the first time

Tags: android-studio

I've disabled the default Splash screen by adding this line to themes.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

and I have implemented a custom splash screen, but I'm facing a weird issue with it. When I first open the app the splash screen loads twice. but all the times after the first time it works fine. So when ever I install the app and open it for the first time the splash screen loads twice.

Here is my SplashScreenActivity:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(4000);
                    onBoardingScreen = getSharedPreferences("onBoardingScreen", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    boolean isFirstTime = onBoardingScreen.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
                    if(isFirstTime)
                    {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = onBoardingScreen.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("firstTime",false);
                    editor.apply();
                    //startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,onBoarding.class ));
                   //  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), onBoarding.class);
                     Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, onBoarding.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                     finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){

                }

            }
        }; thread.start();
```

so when the first if condition is met, the issue happens. Why is that? can you please help?

Here is onBoarding Activity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_boarding);
        //Hooks
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.slider);
        dotsLayout = findViewById(R.id.dots);
        letsGetStarted = findViewById(R.id.get_started_btn);
        next_btn = findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
        if (getActionBar() != null) {
            getActionBar().hide();
        }
        letsGetStarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(onBoarding.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //Call adapter
        sliderAdapter = new sliderAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);
        //Dots
        addDots(0);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(changeListener);
    }
```

I tired solutions from here: [Splash screen appears twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861085/splash-screen-appears-twice)
but they didn't work for me.